Log Decode Instruction from webSocket
For three days now I have been trying to figure out how to Decode these codes when there is no proper documentation and no proper instructions.
log =>  {
signature: '5333hEQWwnuaY6tJcxbpEBzZNJrRYG48KmMGidQT4wcnR49YJqn9wqFsgyBuUCSfKfNUKf3KNsonvQ6pHfL6G7Pj',
err: null,
logs: [
'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke 1',
'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success',
'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke 1',
'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success',
'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke 1',
'Program log: CreateIdempotent',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
'Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1569 of 129632 compute units',
'Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
'Program log: Initialize the associated token account',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
'Program log: Instruction: InitializeImmutableOwner',
'Program log: Please upgrade to SPL Token 2022 for immutable owner support',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1405 of 123045 compute units',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3158 of 119163 compute units',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 22315 of 138037 compute units',
'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success',
'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke 1',
'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke 1',
'Program log: Instruction: SyncNative',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3045 of 115572 compute units',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
'Program JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 invoke 1',
'Program log: Instruction: Route',
'Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 invoke [2]',
'Program log: ray_log: AwDh9QUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAADh9QUAAAAA790dTfvDWg1BJ6mzVwYAAJfCybeEDAAA',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]',
'Program log: Instruction: Transfer',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4736 of 64503 compute units',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]',
'Program log: Instruction: Transfer',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4645 of 56786 compute units',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
'Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 consumed 29406 of 80967 compute units',
'Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 success',
'Program JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 invoke [2]',
'Program JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 consumed 2025 of 48582 compute units',
'Program JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 success',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
'Program log: Instruction: TransferChecked',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 6147 of 42317 compute units',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
'Program JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 invoke [2]',
'Program JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 consumed 2025 of 33986 compute units',
'Program JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 success',
'Program JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 consumed 82095 of 112527 compute units',
'Program return: JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 xWlSemkMAAA=',
'Program JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4 success',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke 1',
'Program log: Instruction: CloseAccount',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2915 of 30432 compute units',
'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success'
]
How can fetch like this without using getAccount and getTransaction or others func like this : 

LINK
